# Remote data not accessible - disable popup

Tags: vba, excel

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
```

does not work. (I was trying to put in in the workbook open event).
The popup appears on file open, together with other usual popups like 'This workbook contains links to other data sources'

I don't want the Remote data is not accessible popup appear at all, but I still want to keep the remote data links in the sheet. Is there a solution to this issue?

Answer (score -1):

You could try

```
Dim xlApp as New Excel.Application
Dim xlWB as Workbook
xlApp.application.displayalerts=false
xlApp.Visible = false
Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Test.xls")
```

This should hide the app alltogether. Remember to close the instance of excel when you are done.

Comment: hide the app? I would like to use the workbook as normal, just without the popup when I open it

Comment: Hiding the new app will only hide the new instance of excel which will only have the data open in it. As far as I am aware it should work as normal? just you reference it in code like xlWB.sheets("Sheet1").range("A1"). What exactly do you do with the file? do you run code on it to get data out or?

Comment: What app are you talking about? I have a single excel file, with a formula that causes the popup to appear. I dont want to see the popup.